# Modifying a github public repository from a travis build

Tags: github, travis-ci

In the build of my first public repository https://github.com/yafred/test-push/ I try to modify my second repository https://github.com/yafred/test

1/ I am using the same personal access token with scope `repo` (GH_TOKEN) that I'm using to deploy releases.

2/ The commands I am executing from the `.travis.yml` are

```
language: generic

script: 
  - git clone https://github.com/yafred/test.git
  - cd test
  - echo "hello" > test.txt
  - git add .
  - git -c user.name='travis' -c user.email='travis' commit -m  refresh
  - git push -f -q https://{$GH_TOKEN}@github.com/yafred/test master
```

I have tried a few variations in the commands based on my searches but I keep getting an authentication error

```
0K$ git push -f -q https://{$GH_TOKEN}@github.com/yafred/test master
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://{[secure]}@github.com/yafred/test/'
```

Is it at all possible ?
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You got a typo in there. Should be ```${GH_TOKEN}```

Comment: You're absolutely right. Silly me.

Comment: What was the typo, I couldn't get it. Please post solution if any, I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: in the git push command: {$ instead of ${